# Mission control and Cmd + Tab not working since Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: macos, mission-control

I upgraded my OS from Mountain Lion to Yosemite yesterday and now Mission Control and Cmd + Tab aren't working anymore. Clicking mission control icon doesn't do anything, although I still have 4 spaces automatically opened upon starting the computer. Also, for instance, when I am on screen #1 and Chrome is opened on screen #2, if I press Cmd + Tab to change to Chrome, the menu bar at the top of the screen will change to Chrome but the screen will remain on screen #1.

So far, I tried, but without success:

1. Rebooting
2. Killing dock process using "killall Dock" and "killall -kill Dock" in Terminal
3. I made sure no other updates were available
4. Browsed internet a few hours to try to find something, but found nothing successful
5. F4 shortcut doesn't work neither

My computer specs are the following:

iMac 27 inches, late 2009,
2.66 GHz Intel Core i5,
8 GB DDR3

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: you mean "killall -kill Dock"

Comment: I also tried it, but also unsuccessful in order to make Mission Control work, although Dock was reseted. Edited it.

Comment: Is this User specific? and did you repair permissions in disk utility? does the mission contrl keyboard shortcut works? or the F4

Comment: There is only one user on the computer, so I do not know, should I create a second user and try it? I do not know what those repair permissions are, I'll look at that. I also tried F4, but not working. I'll edit it concerning F4.

Comment: Open Disk Utility app in your utility folder, then run the repair disk permissions. it is a slim chance the problem is there but it wont harm doing it.

Comment: Disk utility repair permissions did not change anything.

Comment: Final attempt form my site, start in Safe mode to see if it works there.

Answer (score 5):

Try resetting all the defaults for Mission Control. I had the same problem and now it works.

Type the following command into Terminal:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock mcx-expose-disabled && killall Dock
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but sadly I have already downgraded back to 10.8 because I couldn't find anything. How can I mark my question so people do not loose time answering it?

Comment: @A.P. - Your question still needs an answer. It will help other people.

Comment: This works for Yosemite with the following adjusted command:  "defaults delete com.apple.dock && killall Dock".

Comment: This works with Mojave too!